# Exceeding Quota For "Database Units - Web Edition"

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure subscription and I am exceeding the quota of "1 DB Unit" for "Database Units - Web Edition".

I am not at all sure what this means. I have a mobile service, blob storage, web site, and 5 SQL Databases setup. What exactly is classified as a "Database Unit" and "1 DB Unit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Windows Azure billing team has decided to introduce an incremental pricing strategy for SQL Database, thus tremendously reducing the original price, they introduced the term "Database Unit".

Speaking of "Exceeding quota" I suspect that you are using MSDN [PRO|PREMIUM|ULTIMATE] subscription benefits. It is stated quite clearly what a Database Unit is [on the page where all these benefits are detailed](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits/):

> ... This offer includes a 1DU Web Edition SQL Database (1DU=1GB) to
>   use for any services you deploy to your subscription, ...

Which on the [official Pricing Details](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-4) page is displayed as:

> DATABASE UNITS (DU) THAT WILL APPEAR ON YOUR BILL

Comment: Hmm. So I'm only going over my quota specifically for the data stored in the SQL Databases?! And I don't have an MSDN subscription, but thanks. I'll try deleting some databases and see where that goes.

Comment: Then you most probably are working with `Trial` subscription. Only trials and MSDN do have quotas.